# Recursive DataType in Scala

Tags: scala, types, higher-kinded-types, f-bounded-polymorphism

Hi I was wondering if someone could explain this signature I found in the Spark codebase.  It looks like a recursive datatype, it's used to build the query plan so it kind of makes sense.  Does anyone have anymore detailed knowledge of this?

```
abstract class TreeNode[BaseType <: TreeNode[BaseType]] extends Product
```

Comment: "Does anyone have anymore detailed knowledge of this?" is a question about the existence of knowledgeable people in a specific area of research, it is not a valid SO question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is *F-Bounded Types* (or *self-recursive types*). Not scala specific, e.g. equivalent in java

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>> implements Comparable<E>
```

You can read [here](http://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-self-recursive-types/) or [here](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#self-recursive-type)